# Use Headers to download a file in parts

Tags: php, csv, header

I'm trying to make some calculations and download the result, for this I'm using headers but the result is pretty big and I'm getting memory issues.

Here is my code headers code:

```
function download_send_headers($filename) {
    // disable caching
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2020 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // force download  
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");

    // disposition / encoding on response body
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}
```

And here is where I'm getting a problem:

```
$export_model->download_send_headers('tainacan_csv.csv');
foreach($objects as $object) 
{
       $csv_data = $export_model->generate_csv_data($data, $object);
       echo utf8_decode($export_model->array2csv($csv_data, $data['socialdb_delimiter_csv']));
}
```

More code, I changed my aproach to line by line and even so I'm getting memory issues. This the code that generate de CSV.

```
public function generate_csv_data($data) {

    $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');

    $propertyModel = new PropertyModel;
    $objects = $this->get_collection_posts($data['collection_id']);
    $facets = CollectionModel::get_facets($data['collection_id']);

    //fputcsv($df, array_keys(reset($objects)), $data['socialdb_delimiter_csv']);

    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        $csv_data = [];
        if ($object->ID == $data['collection_id']) {
            continue;
        }

        /** ID * */
        if ($object->ID != "") {
            $csv_data['ID'] = $object->ID;
        }

        /** Title * */
        if ($object->post_title != "") {
            $value = $object->post_title;
            if(mb_detect_encoding($value)==='UTF-8'){
                $value = utf8_decode($value);
            }
            $csv_data['title'] = $value;
        } else {
            $csv_data['title'] = '';
        }

        /** Description * */
        if ($object->post_content != "") {
            $value = $object->post_content;
            if(mb_detect_encoding($value)==='UTF-8'){
                $value = utf8_decode($value);
            }
            $csv_data['description'] = $value;
        } else {
            $csv_data['description'] = '';
        }

        /** Content * */
        if (get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_object_content', true) != "") {
            $csv_data['content'] = utf8_decode(get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_object_content', true));
            if ($csv_data['content'] != '' && is_numeric($csv_data['content'])) {
                $csv_data['content'] = wp_get_attachment_url($csv_data['content']);
            }
        } else {
            $csv_data['content'] = '';
        }

        /** Origin  * */
        if (get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_object_from')) {
            $csv_data['item_from'] = get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_object_from', true);
        }

        /** Type  * */
        if (get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_object_dc_type')) {
            $csv_data['item_type'] = get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_object_dc_type', true);
        }

        /** Source  * */
        if (get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_object_dc_source')) {
            $value = get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_object_dc_source', true);
            if(mb_detect_encoding($value)==='UTF-8'){
                $value = utf8_decode($value);
            }
            $csv_data['item_source'] = $value;
        }

        /** URL * */
        if (get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_uri_imported')) {
            $csv_data['permalink'] = get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_uri_imported', true);
        } else {
            $csv_data['permalink'] = get_the_permalink($data['collection_id']) . '?object_id=' . $object->ID;
        }

        /** Tags * */
        $tags = wp_get_object_terms($object->ID, 'socialdb_tag_type', array('fields' => 'names'));
        if (!empty($tags)) {
            $csv_data['tags'] = utf8_decode(implode('||', $tags));
        } else {
            $csv_data['tags'] = '';
        }

        /** Categories * */
        $categories_of_facet = array();
        $category_model = new CategoryModel;
        $categories = wp_get_object_terms($object->ID, 'socialdb_category_type');
        if (is_array($categories)):
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                $facet_id = $category_model->get_category_facet_parent($category->term_id, $data['collection_id']);
                if (!isset($facet_id) || $facet_id == $category->term_id) {
                    continue;
                }
                $categories_of_facet[$facet_id][] = $this->get_hierarchy_names($category->term_id, $facet_id);
            }
        endif;

        if ($facets) {
            foreach ($facets as $facet) {
                $term = get_term_by('id', $facet, 'socialdb_category_type');
                if (is_array($categories_of_facet[$facet])):
                    $csv_data[utf8_decode($term->name)] = utf8_decode(implode(', ', $categories_of_facet[$facet]));
                else:
                    $csv_data[utf8_decode($term->name)] = '';
                endif;
            }
        }

        /** Propriedades de Atributos * */
        $root_category = $this->get_category_root_of($data['collection_id']);

        //$all_properties_id = get_term_meta($root_category, 'socialdb_category_property_id');
        $all_properties_id = array_unique($this->get_parent_properties($root_category, [], $root_category));
        if ($all_properties_id) {
            foreach ($all_properties_id as $property_id) {
                $property = get_term_by("id", $property_id, "socialdb_property_type");
                if (in_array($property->slug, $this->fixed_slugs)):
                    continue;
                endif;
                $type = $propertyModel->get_property_type($property_id); // pego o tipo da propriedade
                if ($type == 'socialdb_property_data') {
                    $value = get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_property_' . $property_id, true);
                    if(mb_detect_encoding($value)==='UTF-8'){
                        $value = utf8_decode($value);
                    }
                    $csv_data[utf8_decode($property->name)] = get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_property_' . $property_id, true);
                } elseif ($type == 'socialdb_property_object') {
                    $property_result_meta_value = get_post_meta($object->ID, 'socialdb_property_' . $property_id);
                    if (is_array($property_result_meta_value) && $property_result_meta_value[0] != '') {
                        foreach ($property_result_meta_value as $property_meta_value) {
                            $array_property_name[] = get_post($property_meta_value)->post_title;
                        }
                        $csv_data[utf8_decode($property->name)] = utf8_decode(implode(', ', $array_property_name));
                    } else {
                        $csv_data[utf8_decode($property->name)] = '';
                    }
                }
            }
            $array_property_name = [];
        }

        /** Arquivos * */
        $array_files = $this->list_files_to_export($object->ID);
        if ($array_files) {
            $csv_data['Files'] = implode(', ', $array_files);
        } else {
            $csv_data['Files'] = '';
        }


        /**             * ************************** */
        //$csv[] = $csv_data;

        fputcsv($df, $csv_data, $data['socialdb_delimiter_csv']);
        unset($csv_data);
    }
    fclose($df);
    //return $csv;
}
```

Comment: Presumably `generate_csv_data` is what generates a large array which you convert to a CSV. Ideally you should have `generate_csv_data` generate actual CSV data and echo it line by line instead.

Comment: I tryed do like this, line by line but even so Apache doesn't stop of cosume memory. It stops at 580 MB of memory consumed

Comment: If output buffering is enabled you need to disable it.

Comment: In php.ini file? I can't change php.ini

Comment: Try running [`ob_end_clean`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) before sending anything

Comment: I tried to put ob_end_clean before send headers, inside generate_csv_data just before start and even inside the loop in generate_csv_data but it doesn't work too

Answer (score 1):

You can change the memory limit with: [`ini_set();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) like so:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

Edit:
I agree on @apokryfos. If you want an more detailed solution, we need more code.

Comment: This is known as the "throw money at it" solution. Unfortunately not everyone can afford it. (In this context money symbolises a finite resource)